# Page number in BIOS interrupts

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, bios

I'm building a small bootloader for x86 as a project. For the moment I'm writing several functions to handle the screen, since it's a bit tedious. Most BIOS interrupt functions involve a page number argument, and I can't tell what this is for.
Wikipedia hasn't nothing to say, I think.

Does anyone know what the page number represents?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of one of these functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's enough video memory to allow multiple text screens side-by-side. The page numbers allow you to do double-buffering, where you draw to an off-screen page, and then when it's ready change the currently visible page to the new one.

See the infamous and still invaluable Ralph Brown's Interrupt List for more (well, a little more) information:

http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0087.htm

In particular, look at int 0x10 AH=0x05, which lets you change the current visible page.

Comment: _There's enough video memory to allow multiple text screens_ ← depending on the video mode, but otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use page 0, which is the default current page.